# Boolean as key in dictionary is causing weird problems?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python and I am currently learning about dictionaries. I was putting random values and types in a dictionary. Here is what is confusing me:

```
stuff = {True: 1234, 1: 2}
print(stuff[True])
print(len(stuff))
```

When you run this bit of code, the output is:

```
2
1
```

How is this the output? Shouldn't `print(stuff[True])` be outputting `1234` and `print(len(stuff))` be outputting `2`? I might be missing something really obvious, but can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: `True == 1`; `bool` is a subtype of `int`.

Comment: @Ryan so Python is actually interpreting `{True: 1234, 1: 2}` as `{1: 1234, 1: 2}`? I guess that explains the `len` problem. But still, why does it choose `2` instead of `1234`, especially since `1234` comes first?

Comment: If you have multiple equal keys, the last one is the one whose value is used. And you can sort of think of it as `{1: 1234, 1: 2}`, but it’s not *really* that; `True` and `1` are distinct but compare as equal with `==`, and dictionary keys are compared based on that equality.*

Comment: @Ryan ohhh ok I get it now I just debugged my program. You are right, the `1: 2` overwrites the `1: 1234` so by the time the interpreter is done reading the dictionary, it has read it as `stuff = {1: 2}`. That explains both problems. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @parrot15, did you receive the answer you were looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though python is dynamically typed, it is considered a bad practice to use heterogenous key types in a dictionary.

Running `{True: 'a', 1: 'b', 1.0: 'c'}` would actually map to `{True: 'c'}`,

This is because `1==1.0` and `1==True`, thus they have the same `hash`.

The end result, is that the first key would be used, and the last value would be updated.

If you want to separate `True` and `1` for some reason, use their type as key as well (e.g. `(x, type(x))`)

```
{(True, type(True)): 'a',(1, type(1)): 'b', (1.0, type(1.0)): 'c'}
```

Comment: I would suggest `(x, type(x))` as effective but less costly than `repr(x)`